# Checking Google Analytics ECommerce - Abandoned Cart

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce, drupal

I'm testing a Drupal site where Google Analytics ECommerce should register if someone abandons their cart. However I've been unable to test if it's working, as I can't figure out where that would register in the first place.  The system supposedly exists and works, but I can't find anything under ECommerce that would allude to it working.  Does anyone know where you would find the data for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have analytics ecommerce setup on the site then all transactions will be recorded. So I suppose that will tell you it's working.

IF nothing is recording past the basket or checkout then make sure the tracking is on all the pages and that the ecommerce tracking code is on the confirmation page.

Answer (score 1):

you must enable ecommerce tracking on the view (profile) settings page for your website. After that, you must implement the ga.js ecommerce tracking methods in your shopping cart pages or through your ecommerce software

[more info here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingEcommerce)